# How to use autopair for double quotes in .tex files (so that typing " leads to ``'')?

Tags: punctuation, emacs, aquamacs

I'm working with Aquamacs 2.3a to compile .tex documents. Typing double quotes `"` one time leads to ``` `` ```. Then writing a word and finishing with `"` again, expands to ``` ``myword'' ```. How can I have autopair to directly give me ``` ``'' ``` when typing `"` once?

I used autopair before to pair "$" in .tex documents, but I couldn't get this to work for the above problem:

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (modify-syntax-entry ?$ "\"")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not trivial.  The double-quote behaviour you currently have doesn't come from autopair but tex-mode.

You can advise it to get the specific behavior you want:

```lisp
(defadvice tex-insert-quote (after maybe-pair activate compile)
  (when (equal "``" (buffer-substring-no-properties (- (point) 2) (point)))
    (save-excursion
      (insert tex-close-quote))))
```

However, you won't get the paired deleting or skipping.  Just inserting.

Comment: I put it in Preferences.el and restarted Aquamacs. Unfortunately, typing double-quotes still gives me `` (bevor the word) and '' (after the word) and not ``'' right away. But I see, it's a non-trivial problem.
Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: It worked for me.  I meant getting comprehensive autopair functionality is not trivial.  Insertion is not too bad.  This would only insert paired quotes when point is after a space.